# How "risky" it is if I lose my passport? Will police investigate how I lost it?

Tags: india, indian-penal-code

I have some stamps on my passport that are not really good, and I don't want any of my family members to see it.

Now, if I lose my passport somehow, and apply for a new passport, would I get a clean passport, without any travel history on it?

Would police investigate if passport is actually lost, or is it carelessness or other reason for its loss?

Any other thing I should worry about if I take this route?

Comment: the passport is a document owned by the government.

Comment: I don't think giving advice on how to lie to the government or commit crimes is appropriate. In general, the passport number may be added to a database and the police may consider if anything suspicious is involved (since e.g. you could pretend to lose it and then give it to a wanted criminal who looks just like you, or sell it to a forger). The obvious thing to consider would be what if you claim it is lost and then it's found. You could always run it through the washing machine a few times instead.

Comment: I can't answer for India authorities specifically, but I can't imagine anyone caring why you lost your passport, nor what exactly they would investigate about it.  Put it in the garbage and go get a replacement in 2 weeks.  Your answer may be different in North Korea, they might strap you to an anti-aircraft gun.

Comment: @TigerGuy Immigration authorities of countries being visited would care, as it could be an attempt to hide denial stamps, particularly of other countries where they don't have database information.

Comment: @user71659 okay, but people lose their passports and get new passports.  I just can't see it being a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

### Losing your passport is fine, happens all the time

**But that’s not what you are talking about, is it?**

You’re intending to deliberately destroy it.

While destroying a passport is not a specific offence under the [Act or the Rules](https://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/PassportAct), your proposed course of action is still illegal.

1. The passport doesn’t belong to you. It belongs to India and deliberately destroying other people’s stuff is illegal.
2. To get a new passport you would necessarily be lying and giving false information on a passport application *is* an offence.

Of course, one wonders why your family are looking at your passport; just don’t show it to them.

Comment: My wife likes to check everything, for no reason. 
What if I drop my passport while traveling on train, Indian trains have open doors and cross many bridges, and it is a popular hobby to come near door while it crossing a mega river ... 
What if I dropped my passport which was in my loose pocket? 
Even if some fisherman finds it 4 months later, does not make much sense..